Is the expected length of a line in a disk proportional to the radius?
Suppose we have two i.i.d random variables $Q_1 = (x_1, y_1)$ and $Q_2= (x_2, y_2)$ that uniformly randomly sample points from a disk of radius $R$, $D_R$. Denote the new random variable $\ell = ||Q_1 - Q_2||$, the length of the line segment between $Q_1$ and $Q_2$. I want to show that $$\mathbb{E}[\ell~|~Q_1, Q_2 \in D_R] = kR$$ where $k$ is some constant.
To prove this, I'm trying to show that WLOG $$ \frac{\mathbb{E}[\ell~|~Q_1, Q_2 \in D_R]}{\mathbb{E}[\ell~|~Q_1, Q_2 \in D_{2R}]} = c $$ where $c$ is some constant. But this boils down to showing that $$ \frac{\int_{D_R}||Q_1-Q_2|| ~dx_1 ~dx_2~dy_1 ~dy_2 }{\int_{D_{2R}}||Q_1-Q_2|| ~dx_1 ~dx_2~dy_1 ~dy_2 } =c$$
I would like to show this without explicitly computing the integral (partly because I came across the problem while trying to solve the integral). I think I'm missing something simple about polar integration in this approach. Or, maybe there is an easier way to show this with conditional expectation. The latter, I think, generalizes nicely when one is asking about the relationship between the expected volume of the convex hull of random sampled points in $D_R$ and the radius $R$. Please don't give direct answers. I'll appreciate a hint.
Thanks!

You're overcomplicating this. Sampling those points on a disk of radius R is the same as sampling them on a disk of radius 1 and rescaling by R. So just see what effect that rescaling has on $\ell$ and you're done

Terminology : replace "line" by "line segment"
